# Error while adding layout update to the widget

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, error, sql, widgets

I am using a theme that has been built on Magento 1.9. Whenever I am trying to add layout update to a widget and save it I am getting the error below.

```
An error occurred during saving a widget: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-ves_kitchen-default-61' for key 'UNQ_CORE_LAYOUT_LINK_STORE_ID_PACKAGE_THEME_LAYOUT_UPDATE_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `core_layout_link` (`store_id`,`area`,`package`,`theme`,`layout_update_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Can someone kindly tell me why is this happening and how I can sort this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error indicates that 61 Id is already in the database table.

When I faced this issue, I have increase auto increment value in a particular table.
Like in your table if you can see auto increment value is 65 then make it 70 or 75 and clear cache.

Comment: Am I suppose to update this in the database table or in the code? And how to increase this auto-increment value?

Comment: First take backup of your table and then change in database table.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the auto-increment value in the table core_layout_update which is a parent of core_layout_link and refreshed the cache as you had suggested. And it worked for me.